# Expedite Sklearn model predictions

Tags: python, performance, rest, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm working on a REST API and am looking for ways to speed up the time it takes to make predictions on my saved Sklearn model.

```
# ###################################
# # MAKE PREDICTION ON SAVED MODEL  #
# ###################################

# Time prediction
import time
start = time.time()

# Recall important variables
start_one = time.time()
data = pd.read_csv("dataset/train.csv")
x = data["ID"]
vec = CountVectorizer()
x_train_vec = vec.fit_transform(x)  # most time-consuming line
total_time_one = time.time() - start_one
print("Time taken to recall variables:", total_time_one)

# Load saved model
start_two = time.time()
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    clf2 = pickle.load(f)
total_time_two = time.time() - start_two
print("Time taken to load the saved model:", total_time_two)

# Declare prediction variable
my_foods = [
    "Burrito",
    "Tacos",
    "Pizza, pasta, and salad",
    "Burger",
    "Steak"

]

# Predict my_foods in the model:
start_three = time.time()
my_foods_vec = vec.transform(my_foods)
response = clf2.predict(my_foods_vec)
total_time_three = time.time() - start_three
print("Time taken to make prediction:", total_time_three)

total_time = time.time() - start
print("Total time elapsed:", total_time)
print("Misc time:", total_time - (total_time_one + total_time_two + total_time_three))
```

Here is what was returned during one of my trials:

```
Time taken to recall variables: 0.31730008125305176
Time taken to load the saved model: 0.11299991607666016
Time taken to make prediction: 0.002086162567138672
Total time elapsed: 0.43245816230773926
Misc time: 7.200241088867188e-05
```

As you can see, it typically takes around 300ms to fit/transform the model with its vocabulary. This might not sound like much, but it doubles the response time of my API, and, depending on the user's Internet connection, can make response times substantially slower.

Are there ways I can expedite this process, and is Sklearn even a good fit for a REST API?

UPDATE: I experimented with pickling the vectorizer, but load times remained the same, and I also used joblib instead of pickle, but load times increased to around 800ms.

Comment: 1) If most of the time is taken up by fit_transform() in the CountVectorizer, could you pickle that vectorizer, and load it the same way you load the model? 2) Can you run a function to load your model once when the API server starts, and then re-use the model for each API call?

Comment: This requires a change in your model, but have you considered setting max_features to reduce the number of features in your CountVectorizer? That would make it smaller. Some of the words in your dataset probably only occur in one or two documents anyway.

Comment: @NickODell, thanks for the suggestion; for some reason, I had not thought to pickle the vectorizer. However, when I did pickle it, the time it took to load the pickled vectorizer was around the same amount of time it took to create it in the first place (~300ms). I also tried joblib instead of pickle, but loading the model took longer (~800ms). In response to your second point, I am planning to run a function, but I'm concerned about the initial load times.